# upload video using FTP

Tags: iphone, objective-c, file-upload, ftp

I have a module which can record a video using iphone camera... and can upload that video using FTP ?

I am unable to upload video file using FTP.

Any ideas ?

Comment: You need to give a bit more information. What module are you using? What error do you get? Exactly what happens?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Upload File to FTP Server on iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266176/upload-file-to-ftp-server-on-iphone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was done using FTP component for iPhone: http://code.google.com/p/s7ftprequest/