# Tranfer audio files to NAS from iPhone using objective c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nas

I want to transfer recorded audio file from iPhone to NAS. is there any solution?
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

You can use several different protocols:

1. FTP (already mentioned)
2. SCP (data transfer over SSH, if the NAS supports it and you need to use the [libssh2](http://libssh2.org) C library for this)
3. HTTP-based: WebDAV if your NAS supports it
4. HTTP-based: "normal" HTTP server with some scripts handling the upload via POST requests

It all depends on what the NAS supports. Talking about the NAS: there are smaller, dumb ones and larger ones which are basically a Linux box. I you have full control over the NAS and own a larger one you can also use its HTTP server and use a script (PHP, Perl, Ruby or whatever) to process the data being send to the NAS. This approach would it also make easy to display more status information on the phone.

In solution 4 for example you can display a webpage with all the already uploaded files to the user and display status messages for example.

Answer (score 0):

Most NAS have a FTP server built in, maybe you could use that approach?

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266176/upload-file-to-ftp-server-on-iphone)