# Let Users Submit To Our Flickr Feed (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, upload, live, feed, flickr

We have developed an iPhone app that uses the camera. We want to let users take a photo and then upload that photo to OUR Flickr feed. All the tutorials I have found seem to having the photos upload to the user's photo feed...

Ideally, users would submit their photos and we would have some sort of interface (not on the iPhone) where we could approve the photos that we want and trash the photos that we don't want. A given photo should not appear in the Flickr feed until it has been approved.

I know that lots of apps have 'Live Photos', does anyone know how they go about making this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have them submit the photos to your own webserver. Then you can have whatever system you want to approve or deny them. As well as having your server submit to your flickr feed.

Comment: That was a thought that I had but wanted to hear it from someone else. Found this post which got my uploads working in a matter of minutes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266176/upload-file-to-ftp-server-on-iphone