# Flickr: Add photos to my personal photostream

Tags: iphone, objective-c, flickr

I found a similar problem in ' [Let Users Submit To Our Flickr Feed (iPhone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5723050/let-users-submit-to-our-flickr-feed-iphone) '.

So, I want other people (using my iOS app) be able to upload photos to **MY** photostream.

I got it working with [phpFlickr](http://phpflickr.com/), using the `setToken` method and not using the `auth` method. ([See bottom section how](http://phpflickr.com/docs/flickr-authentication/)).

But I don't want to use this script and directly upload it to flickr, to cut out 'the middleman' (= my webserver), to limit data usage and server load etc.

I'm using the [ObjectiveFlickr](https://github.com/lukhnos/objectiveflickr) library for communication with flickr. Anyone who can give me a direction to work in or maybe a small piece of working code.

Comment: I should point out that uploading photos you don't own to your photostream is against the Flickr TOS. Unless the users of your app are explicitly giving over copyright of the uploaded images to you then this isn't allowed.