# Upload the file

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I upload a photo to a server with the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125306/how-can-i-upload-a-photo-to-a-server-with-the-iphone)

I want to upload a particular file on server, which is stored in iphone directory.

Simply, to upload any file we can use the "Browse" button.

When you click on this button we can get the file directory and choose any file & we can upload the particular file.

I do the same thing here.

any tutorial or link.

suppose, I am stored the excel file in iphone and i want to upload this file on server which path are not available. but i get the path on using the browse file.In short browse content is my problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801049/uploading-photo-through-programing-in-objective-c/5801303#5801303

Comment: Check out http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/ (ASIHTTPRequest). It's a library built for handling HTTP requests and has an ASIFormDataRequest class that can be used for uploading files to a server.

Answer (score 1):

Which is your problem, uploading file to server, browse content? If it is uploading to server, to upload to HTTP server see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936855/file-upload-to-http-server-in-iphone-programming) so link..[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266176/upload-file-to-ftp-server-on-iphone) link might be helpful too..[This](http://iphone.zcentric.com/2008/08/29/post-a-uiimage-to-the-web/) tutorial tells about uploading an image to file..

Ok browsing part..If  your app is not targeting a jailbroken phone, your app can only access files within its own [sandbox](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/RuntimeEnvironment/RuntimeEnvironment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH2-SW12). You can use [NSFileManager](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [NSDirectoryEnumerator](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDirectoryEnumerator_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to access files in this sandbox.See [this](http://www.theappcodeblog.com/?p=371) tutorial for NSFileManager.

Comment: suppose, I am stored the excel file in iphone and i want to upload this file on server which path are not available. but i get the path on using the browse file.In short browse content is my problem.