# Need FTP Uploading Sample Code or Tutorial in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ftp

I need some good tutorial, help or code to use FTP uploading from my iPhone application to my FTP server.

Kindly guide me a little since i am new in iPhone

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow these question on SO

[Upload File to FTP Server on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266176/upload-file-to-ftp-server-on-iphone)

and this code.

http://code.google.com/p/s7ftprequest/

Comment: i Tried the second one but when i try to put the attached source file into my source code it gives me some Errors.

Comment: errors are mentioned here.. please Guide me m waiting http://code.google.com/p/s7ftprequest/issues/detail?id=6

Comment: did you add CFNetwork.framework and the SystemConfiguration.framework to your project.

Comment: ooh noo. let me add and check.. see...since m new bee i dont know alot about iPhone.. :( thnx for ur guidelines. let me check

Comment: its completely build Thanks alot.... :) Now just let me check if it is working or not to upload file???

Comment: Thanks alot its Done... :) Uploading is successful.