# Upload plist to remote server from iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, upload, plist, dropbox

is it possible to upload an entire plist file to a remote server or to dropbox programmatically from an iPhone?

Any useful info will be helpful. If you have codes pls share thanks! :)

EDIT:

I'm currently using these codes i got it from [Upload File to FTP Server on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266176/upload-file-to-ftp-server-on-iphone/1272889#1272889). But i'm having errors, my plist is in the document dir.

**Function**

```
- (BOOL) uploadData:(NSData *)plistData filename:(NSString *)filename {
NSString *urlString = @"http://site.net/upload.php";

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n",filename]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:plistData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Uploaded: %@", returnString);
return ([returnString isEqualToString:@"OK"]);
```

}

**Call method**

```
[self uploadData:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:dbArray] filename:@"data.plist"];
```

**PHP file**

```
    <?php
$uploaddir = '';
$file = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file;

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "OK";
} else {
    echo "ERROR";
}

?>
```

It just keeps throwing "ERROR"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a generic server you just need to write script (e. g. using PHP) that will accept POST requests. You can then upload your file using `NSURLConnection`.

As usual, the [official documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165-BCICJDHA) has you covered. As for the server side script, that depends on what language/toolkit you choose. PHP’s [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) is just one of the possibilities.

Comment: implemented in the codes above.. take a look.. still unable to upload to server tho.. is my php codes ok?