# Simple sample to upload file

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am looking for a simple sample/tutorial for how to upload a file using ftp for iOS. I am pretty new so it have to be simple without a million features.

Comment: Maybe this thread should help.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266176/upload-file-to-ftp-server-on-iphone

Comment: Does s7ftprequest still exist? Their website is apparently closed

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't use this library, does it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no one line function call, which could do that. Answer by TDeBailleu is simple but require an external server with php support. I've found a [source code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Introduction/Intro.html) which might be usefull to you. It doesn't have "a million features" but might be usefull if you are patient enough.