# Upload image to the PHP server from iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, web-services

I know this question has been asked earlier as well but my issue is a bit different.

I want to upload an image to the PHP server and i want to send more parameters along with an image from an iOS.
I searched on the google and found two solutions:

1. Either we will send an image as `Base64` encoded string in `JSON`. Referred [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153776/convert-base64-string-to-an-image-file).
2. Or we will upload an image to server using form data. I have referred this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266176/upload-file-to-ftp-server-on-iphone). If someone refers me this way, then please help me to add more parameters in this API.

Now my question is, which one is the best way to upload an image to the server and i have to send more parameters (username, password and more details) in the same web service call.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Base64 always the way to go... Do avoid big headers, simplify.

Comment: You will require less memory by using the second approach (multipart encoding using boundaries), since you can stream the data as is. Also your PHP backend will be able to consume it correctly without needing to decode explicitly. Using JSON needs preencoding, using Base64 needs lookahead as well. You don't want to be passing strings  around, which occupy memory; pass streams instead. The header overhead is much less than encoding to Base64.

Comment: @soulseekah Thanks for your response, but the issue is, I want to send more parameters along with an image. How will i pass additional parameters with following second approach.

Comment: @Parcs: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html

Comment: Or, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Multipart_messages if you don't want to read the RFC

Comment: Have u worked before with ASIHTTP ?

Comment: @AkleshRathaur No, i didn't.

Comment: can u pls send ur email id so that i can send demo to u for uploading image on php server

Comment: and your image uploadong url

Comment: My email id is: vinner_2112@yahoo.com

Comment: http://tutorialsios.blogspot.com/2013/08/post-multipart-form-data-using.html

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can upload image from iOS App to `PHP server` like this two way:

**Using [New AFNetworking](http://afnetworking.com/) :**

```
#import "AFHTTPRequestOperation.h"
#import "AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.h"

    NSString *stringUrl =@"http://www.myserverurl.com/file/uloaddetails.php?"
    NSString *string =@"http://myimageurkstrn.com/img/myimage.png"       
    NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:string];

   NSDictionary *parameters  = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:userid,@"id",String_FullName,@"fname",String_Email,@"emailid",String_City,@"city",String_Country,@"country",String_City,@"state",String_TextView,@"bio", nil];

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

    [manager POST:stringUrl parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData)
     {
         [formData appendPartWithFileURL:filePath name:@"userfile" error:nil];//here userfile is a paramiter for your image 
     }
     success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
     {
         NSLog(@"%@",[responseObject valueForKey:@"Root"]);
         Alert_Success_fail = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"myappname" message:string delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
         [Alert_Success_fail show];     

     }
     failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
     {
         Alert_Success_fail = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"myappname" message:[error localizedDescription] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
         [Alert_Success_fail show];

     }];
```

**Second use NSURLConnection:**

```
-(void)uploadImage
    {       
        NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(yourImage);

        NSString *urlString = [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://yourUploadImageURl.php?intid=%@",1];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

        NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
        NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
        [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

        NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", 1]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [request setHTTPBody:body];

        [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    }
```

This both way working fine for uploading image from app to php server hope this helps for you.

Comment: @Pedroinpeace yes that setting at backend in php side

Comment: i tried this method but its not working. My image path is in this format: http://dev-demo.info.bh-in-15.webhostbox.net/dv/abc/ulpoad/post/imageName  how i upload image by using your second method

Comment: AFHTTPRequestOperation not found in my case Please help me with this

Answer (score 0):

Using [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) this is how I do it:

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [params setObject:@"myUserName" forKey:@"username"];
    [params setObject:@"1234" forKey:@"password"];
    [[AFHTTPRequestOperationLogger sharedLogger] startLogging];
    NSData *imageData;
    NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.url.com"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];

    AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
       imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(mediaFile, 0.5);


    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:nil parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData)
    {
              [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"mediaFile" fileName:@"picture.png" mimeType:@"image/png"];
    }];

    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request

    success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON)
    {

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"File was uploaded" message:@""
                                                       delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    failure:^(NSURLRequest *request , NSURLResponse *response , NSError *error , id JSON)
    {
        NSLog(@"request: %@",request);
        NSLog(@"Failed: %@",[error localizedDescription]);
    }];


    [operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
    {
        NSLog(@"Sent %lld of %lld bytes", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
    }];
    [httpClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
```

Comment: AFHTTPClient not found

Comment: @Segev Could you tell me how can this image be grabbed on php server? i am confused how image is uploading to server and by which name it is grabbed?

Answer (score 0):

Try with Restkit

Here is link [Restkit image upload with parameter](https://gist.github.com/johnpryan/3017607)

You can get Restkit help from here [Restkit integration step](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
-(void)EchoesPagePhotosUpload
{
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0), ^{

    [self startIndicator];
});
//NSLog(@"%@",uploadPhotosArray);
NSMutableArray *uploadPhotosByteArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
conversionImage= [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[uploadPhotosArray objectAtIndex:0]];

NSLog(@"conversionImage.size.height %f",conversionImage.size.height);
NSLog(@"conversionImage.size.width %f",conversionImage.size.width);
if(conversionImage.size.height>=250&&conversionImage.size.width>=250)
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
        [self performSelectorInBackground: @selector(LoadForLoop) withObject: nil];        NSLog(@"conversionImage.size.height %f",conversionImage.size.height);
        NSLog(@"conversionImage.size.width %f",conversionImage.size.width);

        for(int img_pos=0;img_pos<[uploadPhotosArray count];img_pos++)
        {
            conversionImage= [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[uploadPhotosArray objectAtIndex:img_pos]];
            NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(conversionImage,1.0);
            [Base64 initialize];
            NSString *uploadPhotoEncodedString = [Base64 encode:imageData];
            //NSLog(@"Byte Array %d : %@",img_pos,uploadPhotoEncodedString);
            [uploadPhotosByteArray addObject:uploadPhotoEncodedString];

        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSString *photo_description=[webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:                        @"document.getElementById('UploadPicsDesc').value"];
            NSString *uploadPhotoImageName=@"uploadPhoto.jpg";
            NSDictionary *UploadpicsJsonResponseDic=[WebserviceViewcontroller EchoesUploadPhotos:profileUserId imageName:uploadPhotoImageName Image:uploadPhotosByteArray PhotoDescription:photo_description];
            //NSLog(@"%@",UploadpicsJsonResponseDic);
            NSString *UploadPhotosStatusString=[UploadpicsJsonResponseDic valueForKey:@"Status"];

            NSLog(@"UploadPhotosStatusString :%@",UploadPhotosStatusString);
            NSString *uploadPhotosCallbackstring=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"RefreshForm()"];
            [webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:uploadPhotosCallbackstring];
        });
    });
}
else {
    UIAlertView *ErrorAlert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Please Upload Photo Above 250x250 size" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [ErrorAlert show];
    NSLog(@"conversionImage.size.height %f",conversionImage.size.height);
    NSLog(@"conversionImage.size.width %f",conversionImage.size.width);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)uploadImage
{

NSString *mimetype = @"image/jpeg";
NSString *myimgname = _txt_fname.text; //@"img"; //upload image with this name in server PHP FILE MANAGER
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSData *imageDataa = UIImagePNGRepresentation(chooseImg.image);
NSDictionary *parameters =@{@"fileimg":defaults }; //@{@"uid": [uidstr valueForKey:@"id"]};

AFHTTPRequestSerializer *serializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
//here post url and imagedataa is data conversion of image  and fileimg is the upload image with that name in the php code
NSMutableURLRequest *request =
[serializer multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:@"http://posturl/newimageupload.php"
                                parameters:parameters
                 constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
                     [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageDataa
                                                 name:@"fileimg"
                                             fileName:myimgname
                                             mimeType:mimetype];
                 }];

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
//manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation =
[manager HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                 success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                                     NSLog(@"Success %@", responseObject);
                                     [uploadImgBtn setTitle:@"Uploaded" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                                     [chooseImg setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"invoice-icon.png"]];

                                     if([[responseObject objectForKey:@"status"] rangeOfString:@"Success"].location != NSNotFound)
                                     {
                                         [self alertMsg:@"Alert" :@"Upload sucess"];
                                     }

                                 } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                     NSLog(@"Failure %@", error.description);
                                     [chooseImg setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"invoice-icon.png"]];
                                     uploadImgBtn.enabled = YES;

                                 }];

// 4. Set the progress block of the operation.
[operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, NSInteger totalBytesWritten, NSInteger totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {

    float myprog = (float)totalBytesWritten/totalBytesExpectedToWrite*100;
    NSLog(@"Wrote %f ", myprog);
}];

// 5. Begin!
[operation start];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this this is work for me.

```
    NSData *postData = [Imagedata dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:apiString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *err;
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];


    NSError *jsonError;
    NSData *objectData = [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *responseDictft = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectData
                                                                   options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                                     error:&jsonError];
```