# Is possible to convert a NSData to image in server side?

Tags: php, ios, objective-c

I have a code who send to the server in method POST a NSData (From an UIImage), When the server arrives at NSData she comes in the following way:

```
<6f732070 726f6475 746f7320 636f6d70   ........... 7261646f 73206465 73746520 72656369 626f2e0a>
```

Now I want to know if is possible to get this string (NSData), and convert again to a image, this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

`NSData` is not a string. It is an `NSObject`. PHP cannot decode these objects. I would recommend sending it as an image instead of overcomplicating things.

Answer (score 0):

Try answers given in following stackoverflow questions on how to upload image using ios.

1. [ios Upload Image and Text using HTTP POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564833/ios-upload-image-and-text-using-http-post)
2. [Upload image to the PHP server from iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20728317/upload-image-to-the-php-server-from-ios)
3. [Objective C: How to upload image and text using HTTP POST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5422028/objective-c-how-to-upload-image-and-text-using-http-post)