# How to update content with same image url in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to update only content in the image URL but URL should remains same  [example](https://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif)  this URL having google image i want to update new image with same URL. If someone have done this then please give me a guidance or tutorial to get rid of this.

Comment: remove the old image in the server and upload a new image with the same name and in the same path.

Answer (score 0):

This is not something you'll be able to do from an iOS app

The `logo.gif` file exists on the server (`www.google.com`), which serves you that image when you make a request to that endpoint (`https://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif`)

The only way to **change** that image is **if the image on the server changes**.

So from a client (iOS) perspective, you are at the mercy of the server you are requesting from.  In some cases, there may exist a Web API that you can hit, and upload the new image you want, and then the webserver will take that new image and overwrite the old one so that the next request for the image at that url (endpoint) will return the new image

However, unless you have access to the webserver source, it is not likely that you'll be able to just update images on websites

EDIT: note that if you are wondering how to upload an image to a server in Objective-C, that is a different question (See [Upload image to the PHP server from iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20728317/upload-image-to-the-php-server-from-ios) as an example)