# Where do I place this code in Xcode

Tags: php, ios, xcode

I am trying to implement code in answer of this link

[Upload File to FTP Server on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266176/upload-file-to-ftp-server-on-iphone/1272889#1272889)

I know that this code goes into my php file in my server website

```html
<?php
$uploaddir = 'photos/';
$file = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file;

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "OK";
} else {
    echo "ERROR";
}

?>
```

and this code goes into my webview controller, correct me if I am wrong

```html
- (BOOL)uploadImage:(NSData *)imageData filename:(NSString *)filename{


    NSString *urlString = @"http://www.yourdomainName.com/yourPHPPage.php";

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n",filename]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *returnString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];

    return ([returnString isEqualToString:@"OK"]);
}
```

What about this code?

```html
[self uploadImage:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image, 1.0) filename:imageName];
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get fast and useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

your code snippets are in Objective-C and are using old (if not deprecated) APIs. What is your minimum iOS version you target?

You should probably look at [NSURLSession](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlsession) class. There is plenty of useful [tutorials](https://www.raywenderlich.com/67081/cookbook-using-nsurlsession) on this topic.